# What cards discount Ninjutsu?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Thinking about making a [Satoru Umezawa](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Satoru%20Umezawa) deck, wondering what are some good discount options for ninjutsu ability.

I know about [Silver-Fur Master](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Silver-Fur%20Master), but I was wondering if [Cloud Key](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloud%20Key) will work too?

Answer (score 10):

**Silver-Fur Master and [Zirda, the Dawnwaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zirda%2C%20the%20Dawnwaker) are the only cards that reduces Ninjutsu costs.**

Ninjutsu is an activated ability that cards have while they are in your hand. Cloud Key does not reduce Ninjutsu costs because it reduces the cost to cast a spell, not the cost to activate an ability.

Silver-Fur Master specifically affects Ninjutsu abilities, and Zirda affects all activated abilities that aren't mana abilities. All other ability cost reduction effects have restrictions that make them not apply to Ninjutsu.

Many cards that reduce activated ability costs refer to something like "activated abilities of creatures". "Creatures" in this case refers to creature permanents, not creature cards in any other zones, because of [rule 109.2](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Object):

> If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t refer to a specific zone or include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

Since they don't affect creature cards in your hand, they don't reduce Ninjutsu costs.

Comment: In particular, there are a few cards that reduce "activated abilities of creatures", but a card doesn't become a creature until it's a permanent on the battlefield.

Comment: Worth noting that since Glenn is asking about this for a "Satoru Umezawa deck" they likely are asking about Commander/EDH, in which case Zirda would be illegal for their deck due to color identity.